# Reference for a stopping-time problem

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, stopping-times

I am looking for a reference (perhaps an example in a text or an article) for the following stopping-time problem. I suspect the problem is well known.

> Random variables in an i.i.d. sequence $\langle X_n: n\ge1\rangle$ are summed until the sum first exceeds a given value $\alpha$. I'm interested in two random variables: the number $N$ of summands needed for the sum to first exceed $\alpha$, as well as the value  of this sum $S=\sum_{n=1}^N X_n\ge\alpha$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} X_n<\alpha$.

I've done some numerical experiments. It looks like $N$ has something like a Poisson distribution with parameter $\alpha/E[X_n]$, and $S$  looks like the portion of a normal distribution above the mean. Perhaps there's a distribution for the $X_n$'s where $N$ and $S$ can be simply described in terms of well-known distributions, but my formal calculations for these make me pessimistic.

Comment: any distributional specification for $X_1$? It is necessary to give specific solutions to first hitting time problems

Comment: The only restriction I've considered on the $X_n$'s is that they have positive support. Barring that, any distribution that leads to a "nice" solution for $N$ and $S$ is fine by me.

Comment: If you did your numerical experiments using an exponential distribution then you would get the sort of results you report (though the Poisson distribution is in effect shifted up by $1$).  But you would get different results if you used a different distribution for $X_n$: for example with a uniform distribution on $[0,2\mu]$ with the same mean, you would get a narrower distribution for $N$, and (as the target $\alpha$ gets large) an almost triangular distribution for $S$ on $[\alpha, \alpha+2\mu]$

Comment: @Henry: Yes, I've noticed the triangular-looking distribution for $S$ when $X_n$ is uniform. In the general case, I can write down equations for the density of $S$ and $N$ based on the density of $X_n$ and their iid sums.  I just figured that in some context somebody has already worked on this problem and has got something simpler.